# Nested dynamically added content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a form which allows the users to add additional content on the fly. The structure of the form is such that there are three dimensions to the form data, i.e., like a movie can play at different theatres and each theatre can have different showing times. The form, therefore has grandparent, parent and child divs, and the parent & child divs can be added to on the press of a button.

Here's a slimed-down version of the code for clarity

```
<div id="grandparent">
    <div id="parent">
        Parent 1
        <div id="child">
            Child 1
        </div>       
    </div>
    <button id="addChild">Add Child</button>
</div>
<button id="addParent">Add Parent</button>

<script>
$(function() {
var grandparent_div = $('#grandparent');
    var parent_div = $('#parent');
    var child_div = $('#child');
    var p = $('#grandparent div#parent').size() + 1;
    var c = $('#parent div#child').size() + 1;
    $('#addChild').on('click', function() {
        $('<div id="child">Child '+c+'</div>').appendTo(parent_div);
    });
    $('#addParent').on('click', function() {
        $('<div id="parent">Parent '+p+'<div id="child">Child 1</div><button id="addChild">Add Child</button></div>').appendTo(grandparent_div);
    });
});
</script>
```

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/u2vUT/

I can create parent nodes fine, and I can even create child nodes of parents on the first level - the problem comes when trying to add children of dynamically-added parents. It's probably because the 'addChild' button is no longer unique, so `$('#addChild').on('click')` can't reference it. So, is there a way to make this work (preferably elegant!)?

Comment: Use classes and event delegation: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/.

Comment: Ids **must** be unique; there's your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use ids, use class

```
<div id="grandparent">
    <div class="parent">Parent 1
        <div class="child">Child 1</div>
    </div>
    <button class="addChild">Add Child</button>
</div>
<button id="addParent">Add Parent</button>
```

then

```
$(function () {
    var grandparent_div = $('#grandparent');
    var parent_div = $('.parent');
    var child_div = $('.child');
    var p = grandparent_div.find('.parent').size() + 1;

    grandparent_div.on('click', '.addChild', function () {
        $('<div id="child">Child ' + ($(this).siblings().length + 1) + '</div>').insertBefore(this);
    });
    $('#addParent').on('click', function () {
        $('<div class="parent">Parent ' + p + '<div class="child">Child 1</div><button class="addChild">Add Child</button></div>').appendTo(grandparent_div);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sJas9/)

Comment: Hi! I'm facing the similar problem with an addition that a child can add multiple of its own children and every one of those children can add their own children. I've forked your JsFiddle and made some changes http://jsfiddle.net/basitsaeed/fSdj3/2/
This is my original jsFddle (http://jsfiddle.net/Z9SBa/18/). Can you help me in this regard? Thank you in advance